# Completion block for GPS coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

As my apps enables the user to get their location every now and then, I could really use the ability to get the location in a completion block. At the moment I've set up a notification using

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("functionToRun", object: nil)
```

When the user request the location, I just run this function

```
func getLocation() -> CLLocation {
    locationManager.requestLocation()
    return location
}
```

However this is updating the location which can take a while, and just returning the latest location, can I implement this in a completion block, so I can get the actual location?

Comment: You can store the completion closure in a property and then invoke the closure from `didUpdateLocations`. It is basically a delegation pattern except you are passing the closure to the function rather than setting a delegate

Comment: Thanks! Could you post an answer with a simple example? Would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`CLLocationManager` doesn't exactly work this way but you could easily use something like the [CLLocationManager-blocks](https://github.com/axldyb/CLLocationManager-blocks) cocoa pod to get this functionality. Just read through the documentation to make sure it behaves the way you expect it to.